# Can anyone explain this WPF combobox behaviour?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

1. Create a WPF application (I'm using VS2013 Community).
2. Add a ComboBox, name it cboTest.
3. In MainWindow.xaml.cs, add these 3 lines after InitializeComponent:

   ```
   for (int i = 100; i >= 0; i--)
       cboTest.Items.Add(i.ToString());

   cboTest.Text = "11";
   ```
4. The cboTest.Text can be set to display any number from 100 down to 11, plus 0. Numbers 10 to 1 do not display.
5. If you change the loop limit to 200, you can display from 200 down to 21, plus 0. It is always the last 10% that won't display.

Comment: Have you repeated the steps you mentioned and reproduced the problem? I can't.

Comment: Rebuilt 3 times, and rebooted just in case. The odd behaviour here is still consistent here.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't reproduce. Can your co-workers reproduce it? What have you tried to debug it? Did you checked the items count of the combobox?

Comment: I have no programming coworkers. Yes, items count is 101 for loop of 100, and they all display correctly. I added a TextBox and Button with a click event:
   cboTest.Text = TextBox.Text;
Same behaviour every time.

Comment: Try to run it with a different PC and see if problem persists. If not, then something wrong with the machine(maybe reinstalling .net framework could fix it)

Comment: Yes problem is consistent on other computers.Sample available at: http://sac.school.nz/test.zip

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have acknowledged there is a bug in the WPF combobox.

Reason: if the menu items are 100, 99, 98... 0 and you try to set the .Text to 10, the typeahead matches 100 first, finds the strings don't match, and stops.

Workaround: set the .SelectedIndex instead.